# unmanaged unions with char array

Tags: c#, union, unmanaged

I have the following in C++:

```
struct TestA {
    int i;
    char text[512];
};

struct TestB {
    double n;
    char text[512];
};

union TestUnion {
    struct TestA a;
    struct TestB b;
};

int fnUnmanagedDLL(int which,TestUnion *);
```

I tried declaring a C# wrapper like this:

```
public class WrapperClass
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct TestA
        {
            public int i;
            [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 512)]
            public string text;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct TestB
        {
            public double n;
            [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 512)]
            public string text;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct TestUnion
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public TestA a;

            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public TestB b;

        }

        [DllImport("UnmanagedDLL.Dll")]
        public static extern int fnUnmanagedDLL(int which,ref TestUnion obj);
    }
```

As soon as I run a program that references WrapperClass.TestUnion, I get " Could not load type 'TestUnion' from assembly 'UnmanagedToManaged, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.".

This is just a test program.  I did see the suggestion in another question for removing the untion.  However, I do not know which structure will be filled by the DLL in advance.  Can anyone offer advice on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way that the default marshaller could handle this automatically.  It cannot know how to marhsal the struct when returning from unmanaged function since there is no way for it to know which part of `TestUnion` it should be using.  You'll have to do the marshaling manually by changing your p/Invoke definition to take an IntPtr, allocated a buffer, and then manually marshaling to the correct type.

In the example below I am assuming that the return value of `fnUnmanagedDLL` is how you determine which type of structure that it filled in.

```
public class WrapperClass
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct TestA
    {
        public int i;
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 512)]
        public string text;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct TestB
    {
        public double n;
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 512)]
        public string text;
    }

    public struct TestUnion  // Removed marshal attributes since they cause exceptions
    {
        public TestA a;
        public TestB b;
    }

    [DllImport("UnmanagedDLL.Dll")]
    private static extern int fnUnmanagedDLL(int which, IntPtr obj);

    public static int UnmanagedDLL(int which, ref TestUnion testUnion) {
       IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(
                Math.Max(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TestA)),
                         Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TestB)));

       int returnType = fnUnmanagedDLL(which, buffer);
       switch (returnType) {
           case 1: // What ever fnUnmanagedDLL returns for TestA
              testUnion.a = (TestA)Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, typeof(TestA));
              break;
           case 2: // What ever fnUnmanagedDLL returns for TestB
              testUnion.a = (TestB)Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, typeof(TestB));
              break;
       }

       Marhsal.FreeHGlobal(buffer); // Need to manually free the allocated buffer

       return returnType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that information.  For anyone else reading this, there are a couple of typos:

Comment: The buffer is only four bytes in size.   So, is there a way to account for the string?   Also, I would have expected it to be bigger given the one structure has a double.